# How to create a new list or set object for an inner dictionary key so that the same object is not repeatedly being updated?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, defaultdict

I'm trying to create an inner dictionary that has values stored in a list or set object (using a set for this example).

```
t = [('Jobs', set()), ('Titles', set())]
inn_d = lambda: dict(t)
```

And creating a default dictionary and passing `inn_d` into that.

```
d = defaultdict(inn_d)
```

When creating the entries for `d` and the outer keys, both values for each inner key gets updated.

```
d['A']['Jobs'].add('Cook')
d['B']['Titles'].add('President')
d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000016691157DC0>, {'A': {'Jobs': {'Cook'}, 'Titles': {'President'}}, 'B': {'Jobs': {'Cook'}, 'Titles': {'President'}}})
```

When it should be

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000016691157DC0>, {'A': {'Jobs': {'Cook'}, 'Titles': set()}, 'B': {'Jobs': set(), 'Titles': {'President'}}})
```

I know that the same set object for both `Jobs` and `Titles` is getting called - I am not sure how to create a new set object when creating the inner dictionary.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new one each time like this:

```
def inn_d():
    return {'Jobs': set(), 'Titles': set()}
```

By the way, [named lambdas are bad practice](/q/38381556/4518341).

Comment: It looks like I get the same result. Is this the right way to go about it with this?
`inner = inn_d()`

`d = defaultdict(lambda: inner)`

Comment: @user2059363 No, `d = defaultdict(inn_d)`. You can also check out [my full test code](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/b89241ae6a6d9df1a78ae036c8ef2bf2).

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you very much. Is my understanding correct that by not including the parentheses in `d = defaultdict(inn_d)`, we make `inn_d` callable instead of returning the dict, which returns a new object every time it is called?

Comment: @user2059363 np! I'm not sure what you're asking though. `inn_d` is already callable since it's a function, and dicts are not callable.

Comment: Basically `inn_d` which returns `<function inn_d at 0x0000016690EFCCA0>` and `inn_d()` which returns `{'Jobs': set(), 'Titles': set()}`, the latter which still updates all values in each key and (from my little understanding) is because `inn_d()` returns the same object? - if that makes sense...

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to create `d = default(inn_d())` this way anyway, as I get `TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`

Comment: @user2059363 `inn_d()` returns a new dict each time, but if you capture its return value like you did with `inner = inn_d()`, `lambda: inner` will always return the same dict.

Comment: Makes sense. Learned so much from just this use case, thanks a bunch

Comment: @nalgene np! Check out [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder to start wrapping your head around how it really works